# a window redirect URL not allowing pop up in IE 11

Tags: javascript

I've a portal redirect html page which I open on click of a button on my portal html with **window.open** method and in the body of redirect html I set the **location.href** = "actual destination URL" under script tag to send to the destination page.

In destination page there are several button present which opens up different functionality. However in IE 11 when we redirect to to the page from portal the button pop ups are not working.

If i click the URL directly from browser the popups works. only redirect via **window.open** is preventing the pop-ups in child page. Earlier This problem was observed in  IE 9 also and then adding ***window.opener=null*** before ***location.href="actual destination URL"*** solved the problem.

Can you advise what can be done in IE 11 for this?

Comment: "`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_ ..."` [Help Center - What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: make sure that the redirect is happen as a direct result of user input, such as clicking a button, and not after an ajax request or setTimeout.